# Getting text displayed on screen like in Now on tap?

Tags: android

Is that at all possible, or is that a .jar file that Google Now has access to? I am planning to add this to my own app.

Answer (score 0):

Now On Tap uses [the Assist API in Android 6.0+](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html#implementing_your_own_assistant).

However, the device has only one active assistant, and so the user would have to disable Now On Tap (and any other assistant) to use yours. The user will also be warned about the security ramifications of enabling an assistant at the time that they go to make the switch.

Comment: Can it be implemented to android 5.0 or lower?

Comment: @MCOM_Droid: The Assist API is only on Android 6.0+, same as Now On Tap. If you want the same behavior as Now On Tap (long-press HOME, get information), that's the Assist API.